# Null Reference Error Trying to Retrieve Authentication Methods for a User using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get details about a User using Microsoft Graph (and then to ultimately update that information). I can retrieve a list of users with basic information (display name, id, user principal name) but all related collections are null.

Code below

```
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "clientId";
var clientSecret = "secret";
var scopes = new List<string> { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

// 1 - Get users
var users = await graphClient
    .Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

// 2 - Pick a user at random
var exampleUser = users[0];

// Null ref exception - exampleUser.Authentication is null
var phoneAuthMethods = exampleUser.Authentication.PhoneMethods;
```

Do I need to specify that I want to retrieve the collection?
This is referencing this nuget package:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a bit more digging and this worked for me:

```
var authMethods = graphClient.Users[user.Id].Authentication;
```

And similarly to add a new method (my ultimate goal) was this:

```
await graphClient.Users[user.Id].Authentication.PhoneMethods.Request().AddAsync(new PhoneAuthenticationMethod
{
    PhoneNumber = "foobar number",
    PhoneType = AuthenticationPhoneType.Mobile
});
```